# Install TA-lib issue

Tags: python, ta-lib

I know there are lots of issues about installing ta-lib. I tried some but not working. Example i tried :

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hZIZMMcTQ8c&ab_channel=MartinMayer
2. https://pypi.org/project/TA-Lib/

For the first, i have this environment :

```
Python 3.9.9 (tags/v3.9.9:ccb0e6a, Nov 15 2021, 18:08:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

I dll that : TA_Lib-0.4.22-cp39-cp39-win32 here ([https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib))

And this is the issue :

```
C:\Users\****>pip3 install TA_Lib-0.4.22-cp39-cp39-win32
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement TA_Lib-0.4.22-cp39-cp39-win32 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for TA_Lib-0.4.22-cp39-cp39-win32
```

(i tried with win64 too).

And with the second solution, i dll the zip and unzipped at C:, i opened visual studio prompt command and tried the command "nmake" but nothing is working

EDIT for comment :

```
C:\Users\bapti>pip install TA-lib
Collecting TA-lib
  Downloading TA-Lib-0.4.23.tar.gz (269 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 269 kB 3.2 MB/s
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\bapti\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from TA-lib) (1.21.4)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for TA-lib, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: TA-lib
    Running setup.py install for TA-lib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\bapti\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\bapti\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4qndp13d\\ta-lib_891a0e91e37348bb9618707395c37102\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\bapti\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4qndp13d\\ta-lib_891a0e91e37348bb9618707395c37102\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\bapti\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-m24m3ndf\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\bapti\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Include\TA-lib'
         cwd: C:\Users\bapti\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4qndp13d\ta-lib_891a0e91e37348bb9618707395c37102\
    Complete output (27 lines):
    C:\Users\bapti\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4qndp13d\ta-lib_891a0e91e37348bb9618707395c37102\setup.py:77: UserWarning: Cannot find ta-lib library, installation may fail.
      warnings.warn('Cannot find ta-lib library, installation may fail.')
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\talib
    copying talib\abstract.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\talib
    copying talib\deprecated.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\talib
    copying talib\stream.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\talib
    copying talib\test_abstract.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\talib
    copying talib\test_data.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\talib
    copying talib\test_func.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\talib
    copying talib\test_pandas.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\talib
    copying talib\test_polars.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\talib
    copying talib\test_stream.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\talib
    copying talib\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\talib
    running build_ext
    building 'talib._ta_lib' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\talib
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\ta-lib\c\include -IC:\Users\bapti\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include -IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\cppwinrt /Tctalib/_ta_lib.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\talib/_ta_lib.obj
    _ta_lib.c
    talib/_ta_lib.c(680): fatal error C1083: Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier includeÿ: 'ta_libc.h'ÿ: No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.30.30705\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\bapti\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\bapti\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4qndp13d\\ta-lib_891a0e91e37348bb9618707395c37102\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\bapti\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4qndp13d\\ta-lib_891a0e91e37348bb9618707395c37102\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\bapti\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-m24m3ndf\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\bapti\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Include\TA-lib' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: How about the official guide that says: `pip install TA-Lib` Does it work?

Comment: For 64-bit Python you need `*-win_amd64.whl` wheels.

Comment: i edited my message

Answer (score 5):

```
pip3 install wheel
```

Then you need to download relevant TA-Lib districution from here [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib), probably `TA_Lib‑0.4.24‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl`,
then

```
pip3 install TA_Lib‑0.4.24‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for MAC OS

1. Install Homebrew from APP STORE
   Restart your PC
2. On terminal
   export TA_INCLUDE_PATH="$(brew --prefix ta-lib)/include"
   export TA_LIBRARY_PATH="$(brew --prefix ta-lib)/lib"
3. on terminal type and execute
   brew install talib (or) arch -arm64 brew install ta-lib (For M1)
   Restart your PC again
4. check installation by typing >>Import talib on python3 terminal
   check version >>talib.**version**

5.if not displayed try once reinstalling using pip install ta-lib

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac:

```
python3 -m pip install TA-Lib
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
!wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
!tar -xzvf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
%cd ta-lib
!./configure --prefix=/usr
!make
!make install
!pip install Ta-Lib

import talib as ta
```

Comment: Please give a bit of context/details, code-only answers are often considered low quality.